# Classifying mongo query operators into equality and range

Tags: mongodb, indexing, query-optimization

So I'm developing a tool for mongo, that will read queries and write which index is required for running the query without a collection scan.

I took the MongoDb performance course, and the lecturer offered a rule of thumb:

> Indices for queries that involve comparing be equality, sorting and comparing by range should be in the form "equality-sort-range".

That means, Mongo will perform best if the first queried "column" is equality-based e.g.: `({'id':123})`, which usually cuts most of the data off the collection, then sort because we can still utilize the index on that column and in the end run on the range filter part, e.g.: `({'age':{$gt:30}})`, because after a range query we can not utilize another indexed column.

Now I want to classify all possible query operators to `equality` or `range`. I found out Mongo's official [list of operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/) and with common sense created two lists, but I'm not sure about some of them. So far this is my list of equality operators :

- '$eq'
- '$ne'
- '$in'
- '$nen'
- '$exists'
- '$type'
- '$mod'
- '$regex'
- '$text'
- '$where'
- '$size'
- '$bitsAllClear'
- '$bitsAllSet'
- '$bitsAnyClear'
- '$bitsAnySet'
- '$'
- '$meta'
- '$slice'
- '$geoIntersects'
- '$geoWithin'
- '$near'
- '$nearSphere'

and these are range:

- "$gt"
- "$gte"
- "$lt"
- "$lte"

Now I'm wondering about:

- "$geoIntersects"
- "$geoWithin"
- "$near"
- "$nearSphere"

They seem like range operators but I can't be sure. Does anyone know?
Also do my two lists make sense?

Comment: Frankly, I would not bother writing such a tool really since a) optimizing queries is a complex topic which goes way beyond the syntax of a query (I'm talking variations of queries here and access patterns - is your app heavy on the read side or also on the write side and so on and so forth...). and since b) the following tool already exists: https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/current/tutorial/suggest-indexes/ It's an enterprise edition only tool IIRC but still...

Comment: reason B makes sense :)
It's good to realize that after I already built the tool.
Actually, I already ran it on my company's production DB and it reduced a lot of time for some heavy and common queries. I just wanted to publish it on Github and wanted to improve its quality before I do.